# How to update static property from subclass in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, static

My Backbone application has a parent class with a static property, along with two subclasses. I am attempting to modify the parent's static property from the child classes, but this does not seem to work. Here is some sample code:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({}, {
  staticProperty: 1,
  getStaticProperty: function() {
    return this.staticProperty;
  },
  setStaticProperty: function(value) {
    this.staticProperty = value;
  }
});

console.log('ParentView.staticProperty: ' + ParentView.getStaticProperty());
ParentView.setStaticProperty(2);

var ChildView1 = ParentView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    console.log('ChildView1.staticProperty: ' + ChildView1.getStaticProperty());
    ChildView1.setStaticProperty(3);  // THIS SEEMS TO DO NOTHING
  }
});

var ChildView2 = ParentView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    console.log('ChildView2.staticProperty: ' + ChildView2.getStaticProperty());
  }
});


var testView1 = new ChildView1();
var testView2 = new ChildView2();
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2agTW/1/

I would expect the following output:

```
ParentView.staticProperty: 1
ChildView1.staticProperty: 2
ChildView2.staticProperty: 3
```

But instead, I get:

```
ParentView.staticProperty: 1
ChildView1.staticProperty: 2
ChildView2.staticProperty: 2  // I THINK THIS SHOULD BE 3
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ParentView' instead:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({}, {
  staticProperty: 1,
  getStaticProperty: function() {
    return ParentView.staticProperty;
  },
  setStaticProperty: function(value) {
    ParentView.staticProperty = value;
  }
});
```

I think Backbone's inheritance model might be a little gaaked (technical term). Or at least, it doesn't do inheritance in the classical sense. In the case of so-called "static" properties, the extend function ends up copying all properties (instance and static) to the child, so, `ChildView1` and `ChildView2` each have their own copies of `staticProperty`. When you call `setStaticProperty` in `ChildView1`, it operates in `ChildView1`'s context, making the `this` operator in it's copy of the function point to `ChildView1.staticProperty`.

I wouldn't say the tutorial is wrong per se - `this` will work if you're not using inheritance, but it's definitely misleading (I suspect the author's use of CoffeeScript hides this particular problem from him). If you want all instances to reference the same properties, I'd always reference the base class and avoid the `this` property.

This article helped me understand Backbone's inheritance quirks - it's definitely worth a read. http://www.erichynds.com/blog/backbone-and-inheritance

Comment: Hm, looks like you're right: http://jsfiddle.net/2agTW/2/. And looks like this guy is wrong, unless I'm misunderstanding him: http://taurenmills.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/backbone-js-with-class-properties/. He says: "Also note that the setMessage function uses the this keyword. Normally, this is reserved for use within instances of a class. But when it is used in a static function, it accesses other static properties or functions within that class. It is important to understand this distinction, because a static function can not access an instance’s properties."

Comment: huh. I'm missing something here. Let me dig into this before you go too far.

Comment: The technique I recommended is good. I updated the answer with some background.